# Why does Van Pelt's gun go up in smoke at the end of Jumanji?

Tags: jumanji

At the end of *Jumanji*, as Alan makes his saving roll, we see everything go up in smoke and get sucked back into the board, starting with the bullet that was about to hit Alan.

But Van Pelt's gun didn't come from the game, he bought it in a gun store. Why did it disappear like that?

Comment: Because, as I said on your other Jumanji question, *the whole world* came from the game.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Jumanji game we see in the movie was started in 1969. From the beginning to the end of the game, everything that happens is a mere illusion generated by the game itself.

Now, Allan “disappears” for 26 years, until 1995. Everything that happens during these years, as realistic as they may seem at first, are *still* part of the game, including Van Pelt's new modern rifle. So, when the game is won everything created by it is reset with the smoke effect, including the rifle.

Comment: This is a very bold statement. Do you have any proof whatsoever to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum Not sure this is "bold". It's just an observation from the events of the movie itself.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an "illusion", rather a branch in time that get's chopped off when the game ends and everything gets reset to right before the game started. I agree with everything else except this part.

Answer (score 3):

The gun vanished not because the game generated it, but because Van Pelt brought it there, brought the bullet there, fired the bullet there.  All consequences of the game were reversed, and if Van Pelt was never there, than neither was the bullet or the gun.

Comment: Even if a random stranger had bought the gun, neither the stranger nor the gun actually exist to begin with.